# Display file content on JSP

Tags: jsp

I'm trying to work on a sample application to display the content of a file on the /tmp directory.
But not being a developer is giving me some troubles.

This is the code I'm using:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="java.io.*, java.net.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>JSP Reading Text File</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
    String fileName = "/WEB-INF/test";
    InputStream ins = application.getResourceAsStream(fileName);
    try {
        if (ins == null) {
            response.setStatus(response.SC_NOT_FOUND);
        } else {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader((new InputStreamReader(ins)));
            String data;
            while ((data = br.readLine()) != null) {
                out.println(data + "<br>");
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

If the file is in the WEB-INF directory on the application, I don't have problems to display it.
But if I try to read it from other directory, I can't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, I end up finding a solution. I don't know if this is between the best practices, but it works.

```
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@page import="java.io.InputStreamReader"%>
<%@page import="java.net.URL"%>
<%@page import="java.io.FileReader"%>
<%@page import="java.io.BufferedReader"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Read Text</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/tmp/test"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while((line = reader.readLine())!= null){
                out.println(line+"<br>");
            }
            out.println(sb.toString());
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```